# Git merge keep and commit conflicted state

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I found some solutions to force an overwrite using `ours` or `theirs` strategies, but is there a way to just commit the merge in the conflicted state?

Before you ask *why* it's not for me, I'm just doing it for someone else.

e.g.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
this is some content
=======
this is different content 
>>>>>>> main
```

Keep this state and commit it. Hopefully should be possible since you can do it manually ? (i.e. `git add` without fixing it)

Thank you!

Answer is just to write the command as a one liner

`git merge main --no-edit || { git add -u . && git commit --no-edit ; }`

will merge main into your branch and if it creates a merge conflict, it will just add the files without changing it and commit it with the default merge message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hopefully should be possible since you can do it manually ? (i.e. git add without fixing it)

Yup, just `git add` the conflicted file(s) without fixing, and commit. If you know there's going to be a conflict, just say

```
git merge otherbranch; git add .; git commit -m 'shut up and merge'
```

Comment: Right, but I meant as part of the `git merge` command; trying to avoid the manual step.

Comment: You'd have to write your own custom merge strategy for that. But I don't see what the issue is. If you know there's going to be a conflict, the merge and add all and commit can be a single command.

Comment: Haha touche.. I didn't even think about using operators to continue and add it / commit it with --no-edit as separate command. Will mark you as answer, thank you!